# Как организовать диапазон внешних ip

Tags: сеть, vlan

Есть управляемый свич в него воткнут сервер - гипервизор, на гипервизоре несколько виртуальных серверов с публичными ip. Вопрос как на сетевом оборудовании правильно поделить диапазон по VLAN-ам, чтобы находясь на виртуальном сервере не было видно как ресурсов доступных во внутренней сети, так и ресурсов доступных для внутренней сети соседнего виртуального сервера.

Допустим отрезаем кусок в 4 адреса. Один из них уходит на адрес сети, второй шлюз, третий на бродкаст, остается 1 адрес который в этой логической еденице может быть использован. Т.е. 3 адреса "пропадают". Какие еще есть варианты?

Comment: Вопрос некорректен, 1 - поделить сети, 2 - ограничения доступа. Сети делить как вам удобно, минимальная сеть возможна в 4 адреса, первый адрес сети, второй адрес аплинка, третий адрес клиента, четвертый броадкаст сети. ИП калькулятор посмотрите в поиске.

Comment: минимальная сеть в 4 адреса и использовать только 2? один под gateway один бродкаст и осталось 2 адреса в случае с внешними ip это так делается? вопрос не про то как делить сети а про то как поступают в таких случаях с диапазонами внешних адресов

Comment: Да, именно так клиентам нарезают транспортные сети. А с диапазоном поступают так как вам нравиться, можете не нарезать вообще, а раздавать как есть, а можете на каждого клиента выделять сеть на 4 адреса. Только остаётся не 2 а один адрес, адрес клиента.

Comment: подождите я чего то не понимаю я клиент, мне дали 4 адреса я хочу каждый из адресов изолировать т.е. не хочу чтобы они могли обмениваться пакетами через мое оборудование я каждый из адресов пихаю в VLAN - уже никак не получится не будет ip под шлюз. Да и расходовать целый внешний ip на шлюз как-то не очень правильно

Comment: Вам дали сеть состаящую из 4 адресов, а не 4 адреса :) Изолировать можно вланами и прочими настройками Л2 левела свитчей, не обязательно делить диапазон на сети.

Comment: ну допустим сеть из 4 адресов - диапазон) но вопрос в том как сделать так чтобы они (адреса) были логически поделены и при этом не потерять ни один из этих адресов на маршрутизацию? Делить обязательно в этом и суть вопроса. Понятно что можно файерволами все закрывать добавляя бесконечные цепочки правил но это по моему совсем не выход

Comment: Зачем делить 64 адреса? Ну если для Вас прям _очень принципиально_ на каждый порт отдельный вилан подать, ну и подавайте, кто мешает-то? На шлюзе бриджуете виланы и вешаете один диапазон адресов туда. Так у каждого устройства будет свой отдельный адрес, один адрес шлюза и 2 адреса сети на всю сеть.

Comment: Многие более-менее управляемые свитчи имеют режим изоляции портов друг от друга. Пилить IPv4 по /30 только с целью изоляции в наше время — непростительная расточительность, IMHO.

Comment: @nobody Это необходимо потому что клиент находясь на сервере видит "соседей" и ресурсы которые доступные только во внутренней сети, а это не безопасно 100%. Если я соберу все vlan в итоге в 1 бридж тогда какой смысл их делить на vlanы(они смогут видеть друг друга) или я не так понял?

Comment: Может я не правильно вопрос поставил, но кто вам сказал что я собираюсь раскидывать vlan по портам? что если в порт воткнут сервер, сервер гипервизор и на нем куча виртуалок которые должны быть по какому-то принципу изолированы. Или для того чтобы разделить 64 адреса на 8 частей мне нужно серверу 8 сетевух поставить?

Comment: Вся зависит от стека технологий который Вы используете. На cisco это private vlan и vlan isolation. На dlink, например, traffic segmentation. Во всех этих случаях, хост будет общаться только со шлюзом но не с соседями.

Comment: Так может вопрос нормально поставить?

Comment: @nobody я просто хочу понять как это организовывают. Тратить 1 порт на 1 vlan, почему я не могу на 1 порте 132 vlan использовать?

Comment: Можете, конечно — tagged vlans — только какое это отношение имеет к текущей формулировке основного вопроса?

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev 1 свич 1 порт и куча vlan это прямое отношение имеет к текущей формулировке вопроса

Comment: Где там что про 1 свитч и про 1 порт? Ваш вопрос — про деление подсетей, а не про настройку оборудования. Присоединяюсь к просьбам переформулировать его корректнее.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev я не прошу конкретного решения с конфигурацией оборудования, я ищу варианты организации такой сети: VLAN, firewall, acl и т.п. не привязываясь к оборудованию. После предыдущей просьбы переформулировать вопрос я его конкретизировал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ещё вариант - технология Cisco IP Unnumbered, а её реализация будет зависеть от производителя вашего шлюза.